# Route ambiguity in AttributeRouting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, attributerouting

I'm trying to create two different routes on two different action methods like this:

```
[GET("/project/create")]
public ActionResult Create()

[GET("/project/{projectId}")]
public ActionResult Details(int projectId)
```

The problem is that when i navigate to /project/create, I'm routed to the Details page, which fails because projectId is not an int.

I realise that I could change the Details route to something like `/project/{projectId}/details` but I would like for it to work the other way.

Also a solution could be to make projectId a string, and internally redirect to the Create action if projectId == "create" but that would feel awful.

I am using [AttributeRouting](https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting) for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using v2.2 or later of attribute routing, you can simply specify a [constraint](https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting/wiki/Route-Constraints) on the project id:

```
[GET("/project/{projectId:int}")]
```

And if pre v2.2 you can use a regex to the same effect:

```
[GET("/project/{projectId(^[\\d]+$)}")]
```

However in the more general case you can specify the [precedence](https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting/wiki/Route-Precedence-Within-a-Controller) of the routes within a controller by setting the `Precedence` property of the attribute:

```
[GET("/project/create", Precedence = 1)]
public ActionResult Create()

[GET("/project/{projectId}", Precedence = 2)]
public ActionResult Details(int projectId)
```

Comment: Thank you that fixed it! I actually tried your first option and thought it didn't work, but I wasnt using 2.2, but your regex did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The order of the actions should set the precedence automatically. So if your Create action was before Details, then you should have no problem. The Precedence property was originally developed to help a user who had partial classes with routes in each.

If you cannot order your routes appropriately, or need further control, then Rich's answer has good tips.